# וִירוּשָׁלָֽ ִם in Siddur Avodat Halev?

Tags: pronunciation

Recently, I switched to Siddur Avodat Halev and noticed a different spelling of וִירוּשָׁלָֽיִם in places like יְהִי רַצוֹן at the end of the amidah. There they spell it ‎וִירוּשָׁלָֽ ִם without the yod. Admittedly, I learned Hebrew later in life, but I feel like this is a mistake. Can someone shed some light on it for me? I have been saying it the same as with the yod.